Bathtub overflow screw doesn’t go all the way in
I removed the bathtub overflow plate and tried reattaching it, but one of the screws won’t screw back in. I brought the screw to a hardware store and they said that the screw is fine - it’s not bent and it has its threads. I tried shorter and longer screws, but am having the same issue.

Is the other screw(s) tight? If so loosen it and see if the screw goes in.

take off the plate ... screw in both screws without the plate

overlay the two screws and hold them against light, do they look the same, with no light in-between

It’s possible the screw hole is stripped and not allowing the screw to thread back in. There could also be rust or other debris preventing proper threading. I would try threading the other screw (that does work) into the hole in question. If successful: replace compromised screw. If unsuccessful, inspect hole for rust or other debris that may be preventing proper threading. Could also try some PB blaster or other thread cleaner. It’s possible the hole threads were damaged, but will need more information first.
